# Is there a way to pipe file data to the user in a way that is seekable (fast forwardable) by the browser

Tags: node.js, express, file, audio, video

I am making a request to one of my cdn's to request the data for a file could be mp4 or mp3. I am then processing that data on my web server and trying to send it to the client as video or audio file. however my issue has been that i cannot find a way to send the data in a way that the browser is able to fast forward the video/audio and when i tried implementing it there are many bugs and some videos dont work. I believe this is because i am not specifying a range to send from the stream so it just resends the same thing every time the browser makes a request for a different part of the audio.

current code:

```
    const range = req?.headers?.["range"] || "bytes=0-";

    if (!range) {
        return res.status(400).send({ err: "Requires range header"});
    }

    let responses = await func.render(req);

    let CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6;
    let start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    let end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, responses?.size - 1); 

    res.setHeader("Content-Range", `bytes ${start}-${end}/${responses?.size}`);
    res.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
    res.setHeader("Content-Length", end - start + 1);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", responses?.type);
    res.status(206);

    responses?.stream?.pipe(res)
```

The only way i can think of is if somehow there is a way to select byte ranges from the stream and pipe only a certain part of the data being returned kindof like how fs can do fs.createReadStream("path", { startByte, endByte }) however i have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. just had to install a library called range-stream and then specify the range i want to pipe from the stream and then pipe that.

`npm i range-stream                                         responses?.stream?.pipe(StreamRange(start, end)).pipe(res);`

This fixed it.